# How to use my api in Flexapp?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, mobile

I'm using restful service with slim framework.

I'm using [FlexAPP](http://flexapp.com/) for Mobile app developing without knowing any code.

example: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/

How can I use this API to pull the JSON data?

1. I created main page and second page.
2. That redirects to "second page" when the "main page image" is clicked
3. I creating an invisible label on "second page" and I'm using "change value" to label.
4. My label value is my article ID value.

My API has this information:

- `wine_title`,
- `wine_description`,
- `article`, and
- `image`

my app screenshot: http://prntscr.com/dgn7ol

How do I get the variable?

Comment: I added some basic formatting to your question so it's easier to read. Please review [Stack Overflow's formatting documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can do this yourself next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a list on the main page. If you are using a list, you need to define a new DataSource. You must add a filter to the DataSource that you created. The filter will provide access to the selected tablerow's data.